# django admin 403 page display error. Unable to find return page when data is inserted

Tags: python, django, iis

when I add or delete data in the admin, I get 404 not found error. I am using windows server.

Error:
[image]

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from home.sitemap import StaticViewSitemap

sitemaps = {
  'static':StaticViewSitemap
}

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('', include("home.urls"), name="anasayfa"),    
  path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {"sitemaps":sitemaps}, name="sitemaps")
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Home urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from . import views

app_name = "home"

urlpatterns = [
  path(r'', views.index, name="anasayfa")
  path(r'galeri', views.galeri, name="galeri"),
]
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Galeri(models.Model):
  baslik = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True, verbose_name="Başlık")
  resim = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Fotoğraf Ekle")

class Video(models.Model):
 baslik = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Başlık")
 video = models.FileField(upload_to="video", blank=True, null=True)
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  "home",
  'django.contrib.sitemaps'
 ]
```

The project was working fine in localhost, but I have such a problem when I upload it to my domain address. The pages of the site are working fine, but there is only this problem in the admin panel.

I'm sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: is there anyone to solve my problem

Comment: `I get 404 not found error` But the error page you show is 403 forbidden. What's the problem you're having? It more likes a permission issue. Did you set app pool have permission to folder?